# calling meta tags through php

Tags: php, html

I have a single header called on different pages through PHP. Similarly the meta tags have also been called a single time in header. But in order to be detected for SEO i have to include separate meta tags for each page. I have tried to make it work in the following way on the header.php of my site:

header.php

```
  <head>
  <?php

      $pgKeywords="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

      $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

  ?> 

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>">
 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>">

 </head>
```

i included the 'header.php' on all other pages (say contact.php, about.php) and called the following only (not the meta tags):

about.php

```
  <?php

      $pgKeywords="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

      $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

      include 'header.php'; 
   ?>

    <div class="cntner_24">

          <a href="contact.php" class="cntct" title="Contact us.">
            <img src="img/button.png" width="18" height="109" class="center_align">
            <img src="img/hover_button.png" width="22" height="21" class="center_align">
          </a>
          <a href="about.php" class="abt" title="Get to know us better.">
            <img src="img/button.png" width="14" height="78" class="center_align">
            <img src="img/hover_button.png" width="22" height="21" class="center_align">
          </a>

    </div>
```

what i want to know is is this the correct way to do it or is there any other correct way to go about so that these meta tags get detected through the SEO ?

Solution (Final Edit):

As the SEO wasn't able to detect tags from different pages (although the solution given by Mr. Rajesh is correct but they wanted all the meta tags on a single page) so i decided to apply a different approach and implemented it all on the 'header.php' page only (explained below).

By prinitng '$_segments' you'll be able to know which segment your required directory (like index.php, contact.php, about.php etc.) is on, say mine was on 3rd place so i put [3] inside if($segments[3]=='index.php')

```
   <head>      
   <?php

      $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
      $segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
      print_r($segments);
      if($segments[3]=='index.php')
          {

   ?>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <meta name="keywords" content=" lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">
   <meta name="description" content=" lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">


   <?php
          }
          elseif($segments[3]=='about.php')
          {
   ?>

    <meta name="keywords" content=" some different meta tag keywords ">
   <meta name="description" content=" some different meta tag description ">

   <?php

          }
   ?>
   </head>
```

So, in this way you can have separae meta tags for separate pages, by just putting the page name through the if-else conditioning.

Comment: Keywords are pretty much meaningless in `SEO` - http://moz.com/community/q/meta-keywords-should-we-use-them-or-not

Comment: If you keep an output buffer you can use `<meta name="keywords" content="%%META_CONTENT%%">` and simply replace `%%META_CONTENT%%` with your actual meta content afterwards before you output your buffer.

Comment: can you please explain in a little detail .. im pretty much new to php .. thank you

Comment: in this case your meta contents will be same for all the pages, which i think is wrong

Comment: where from you get values in $pgKeywords and $pgDesc variables? try to dynamic it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Corrected based on your requirement

**meta.php**

```
    <?php

    function meta($pgKeywords,$pgDesc)
    {?>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
         <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>">
         <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>"><?php
     }?>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php
      include('meta.php');  
      $pgKeywords="Contact us ";
      $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
      meta($pgKeywords,$pgDesc);

  ?>
```

**about.php**

```
  <?php
      include('meta.php');
      $pgKeywords="About us ";
      $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
      meta($pgKeywords,$pgDesc);
  ?>
```

Comment: i need to include separate 'meta tag contents' for different pages (say contact.php, about.php) other than in index.php (according to the example you explained).. including it once in the header won't solve the problem

Comment: Code Corrected based on your requirement

Comment: i have made the changes according to the way you have mentioned, now lets see if the SEO guys are ok with the meta tags ...

Comment: this format is absolutely right .. but turns out they wanted all the meta tags on the header.php page .. so i have editted the code to show what i've done

Comment: Your code is right but when there is more than 10 pages, more number of "if else" statements are required, hence execution time may increased compared with calling the function from each page.

Answer (score 0):

Define keyword and description on page1.php, page2.php etc before including header.php. So your page1.php will be like

```
 $pgKeywords="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
 $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
 include "header.php";
```

where header.php will be like

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>">
 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>">
```

Comment: i have already done that but the SEO guys are not able to detect the meta tags in this way

Comment: Defining meta key values before include header.php should work. You can set keywords and description specific to each page, say about.php will have a separate keyword, description and contact.php will have its own. I'm not sure what is not working in your case

Comment: yes i've worked in the same way you have explained .. write now they are saying that the entire site is having same keywords and description

Comment: can i also include meta tags inside php tags (i mean in php form)?

Comment: remove `<?php

      $pgKeywords="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

      $pgDesc="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

  ?> ` from your header.php